# Touchscreen calibration Linux, Arch, EloTouch xinput_calibrator symbol lookup error

Tags: archlinux, touchscreen, xinput

Im struggling to calibrate a Touchscreen with Linux Tool `xinput_calibrator` under Antergos Arch Linux (kernel 4.15.11-1-ARCH) running on Intel Atom X86 SBC (up-board.com)

Whenever I run the `xinput_calibrator` I got the following error:

> ```
> xinput_calibrator: symbol lookup error: xinput_calibrator: undefined symbol: _ZNK5Cairo7Context16get_text_extentsERKSsR20cairo_text_extents_t
> ```
>
> with debug flag -v additionally:
>
> ```
> DEBUG: Selected Device: Elo Touchsystems, Inc. Elo TouchSytems 2700....
> DEBUG: Not usbtouchscreen calibrator: Not a usbtouchscreen device
> DEBUG Not evdev calibrator: Evdev; Unvalid "Evdev Asix Calibration" property format
> ```

USB Tocuschreen is an ELO Touchsystems 2700 Intellitouch. Antergos Arch with up to date packages

If you need additional Informations/Logs/etc please let me know.

I found one Hit on Google with this error, sadly to an unsolved, closed GitHub Issue.

Comment: This belongs to https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the package in the AUR, I compiled the source with the `--use-gui=x11` flag from the Github Source.

https://github.com/tias/xinput_calibrator

Now it works without errors.